# MediaStore can't list all of videos inside the phone in Kotlin. Why?

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore

I created a function to fetch videos

```
private val projectionVideo = arrayOf(
MediaStore.Video.Media._ID, //ID
MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, //NAME
MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, //PATH TO CONTENT
MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, //DATE
MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE
)

private fun queryVideos(cr: ContentResolver): Cursor? =
        cr.query(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projectionVideo, null, null,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " $SORT_ORDER"
        )
```

In Java

```
public static Uri getContentUri(String volumeName) {
                return Uri.parse(CONTENT_AUTHORITY_SLASH + volumeName +
                        "/video/media");
            }
            /**
             * The content:// style URI for the internal storage.
             */
            public static final Uri INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI =
                    getContentUri("internal");
            /**
             * The content:// style URI for the "primary" external storage
             * volume.
             */
            public static final Uri EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI =
                    getContentUri("external");
```

The issue is this one not showing up any videos in any paths, like 'DCIM', 'WhatsApp Videos' etc. Every video I create with my own app will be correctly inserted, unlike the ones created by the default camera app, unless I open them first.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun getAllVideos(): ArrayList<FileGallery>? {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            var columnVideo:Int ?= null
            var columnFolder:Int ?= null
            var columnDateAdded:Int ?= null

            var absolutePathVideo:String ?= null
            var folderName:String ?= null
            var dateAdded:String ?= null

            val uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            val projection = arrayOf(
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME
            )

            val orderBy:String = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN

            val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
                uri,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                "$orderBy DESC"
            )

            var listVideo = arrayListOf<FileGallery>()

            columnVideo = cursor?.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
            columnFolder = cursor?.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME)
            columnDateAdded = cursor?.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED)

            while (cursor?.moveToNext() == true){
                absolutePathVideo = cursor.getString(columnVideo!!)
                folderName = cursor.getString(columnFolder!!)
                dateAdded = cursor.getString(columnDateAdded!!)
                listVideo.add(FileGallery(absolutePathVideo, folderName, dateAdded))
            }
            return listVideo
        }else{
            return null
        }
    }catch (e:Exception){
        Log.e("ERROR", e.message?:"")
        return null
    }
}
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You can read all videos from [Android Shared Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) with this code

```
    private val videoProjection = arrayOf(
               MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
               MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
               MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
               MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE,
               MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
               MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED)


    context.contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            videoProjection,
            null,
            null,
            "${MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED} DESC"
    )?.use { cursor ->
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
           //read video attr from cursor
           cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(videoProjection[0])) // read video id 
           cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(videoProjection[1])) // read video path 
           // and .....
        }
    }
```

Comment: What' s the difference? Nothing from this changes the behaviour.

Comment: Nothing but you sorted by 'datetaken (DATE_TAKEN)' and iam sorted by 'date_added(DATE_ADDED)' and you use DATE_TAKEN from projection and iam used DATE_ADDED. 
iam using this code in production and worked fine in all android version but if you android version in 10 please read [Android 10 Privacy changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes)

Comment: Sorting is not the main problem. Any ideas about showing all of the videos inside the device?

Comment: sorry if i can't help in this case but i said before this code get all videos of device(in mediaStore) and iam using this code in production for many years. 
can you provide more information about your case such as android version or device model or error you get when run this code ?

Comment: I figured it out: no matter the sorting method, the query function works in both cases, it fetches the right count of videos; the issue was a condition that requires to have a thumbnail to link the video. I was supposed to create a bitmap via ThumbnailUtils for every video without thumbnail path.

Comment: @MehdiYari keep in mind that from `android 11`, `DATE_ADDED` will not work, you have to use `DATE_TAKEN`. so, basically your answer is correct but not for android 11(for me it's working but some times `cursor.getString(dateTakenColumn)` throws null pointer exception)!!